# sending array to emit causes Maximum call stack size exceeded Javascript socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, emit

i have a function:

```
    //  ***************     Send Players their cards     ***************
function sendplayerThierCards(myplayerNum, myN_Cards){
  console.log("sending player: "+ myplayerNum + " their cards: " + myN_Cards);
  socket.emit('playersCards', {
    playerNum: myplayerNum,
    myCards: myN_Cards,
    room: code
  });
}
```

the code that calls it:

```
let myHand = new Array();
for(let i=0; i<5; i++)
    myHand[i] = player1Hand[i]
sendplayerThierCards(1,myHand);
```

If I send a string into myN_Cards emit gets called.
If I send an array into myN_Cards, i get an error:
"Maximum call stack size exceeded Javascript"

the server is here:
https://github.com/tsehnoutka/GameServer

the game code is here:
https://github.com/tsehnoutka/callStackSizeExceeded

This isn't making sense to me as I was able to send an array in another part of my code.
The other Array:

```
var playerInfo = [{
    name: "Red",
    color: "red",
        background: "Coral"
  },
  {
    name: "Blue",
    color: "blue",
        background: "LightSkyBlue"
  },
  {
    name: "Green",
    color: "green",
        background: "Lime"
  },
  {
    name: "Yellow",
    color: "yellow",
        background: "#fcfce8"
  },
];
```

and its function:

```
//  ***************     Send All Players     ***************
function sendAllPlayersJoined(){
  console.log("sending all players info");
  socket.emit('allPlayersNames', {
    players: playerInfo
  });
}
```

Comment: I searched for `sendplayerThierCards` in both your repositories and the code here in your question does not exist in either. In any case, answerers shouldn't be expected to go through your entire repository, and questions should be self-contained. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. **edit** Ah it appears the search feature on Github doesn't span all the branches. The code in the question appears [here](https://github.com/tsehnoutka/cards.js/blob/Euchre/client.js#L311-L319), for anyone interested.

Comment: maybe your array is serialized in the working part of the code. Can you share with us both, working and not working arrays ?

Comment: Sorry  I had the wrong branch.  I have updated the correct link.  I did not expect people to go through my whole repository, I included it for completeness.  My hope was that someone with more experience than me ( as I am new to JavaScript) wold see an obvious mistake, or explain why I am getting this.  I appreciate you looking at it.

Comment: I have created a new project with the bare minimum that reproduces the issue (including the array that send correctly) .  The new code is [here:](https://github.com/tsehnoutka/callStackSizeExceeded)  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

i change the amount of data I was sending at it seems to work,  Instead of the whole Card, I am just sending the rank and suit

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  myHand[i] = {suit: player1Hand[i].suit, rank: player1Hand[i].rank};
sendplayerThierCards(1, myHand);
```

Thanks everyone